# Is jQuery integrated with ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I'm diving into the world of web development after ten years of desktop application development and am currently learning about the many high level concepts, one of them being jQuery.  I've been hearing people mention that jQuery will eventually be integrated into the ASP.NET framework.

1. Has it been integrated into ASP.NET yet?
2. If so, in what version?
3. If so, how would I use it in VS2008?  Can I just start writing JavaScript?
4. If so, is jQuery UI included as well?
5. Can I still have Google host it for me?

I'm sorry if any of these question are strange, remember I'm a noob! :)

Thanks in advance for all your help!

Comment: Thanks, Ionut, my capitilaztion skills are about as strong as my ASP skills :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. It is included, not integrated into ASP.NET MVC. You don't have to use if if you won't want to.
2. It is 1.3.2, but it has specific versions (modifications) for Intelisense. And you can use any version you want.
3. There is an intellisense version that makes it easier to find stuff. But you still can write straight jQuery stuff.
4. No.
5. Yes.

Comment: Thanks, Daniel! When you say it's included, does that mean the JQuery libs are a part of the VS2008 installation and the lib files are included with the rest of the VS2008 files?

Comment: No, its part of the ASP.NET MVC 1.0 templates.

Comment: Rather @David Stratton's link says its an addon.

Answer (score 0):

It is integrated into ASP.NET MVC